# appendChild in a XUL Firefox addon breaks

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am working on a Firefox addon and I currently need to dynamically add menuitems to a menupopup element. I have tried basically all of the approaches on the Mozilla Developer Center and none of them work.

```
    function populateDropdown() {
    var counter = 0;
    for (var key in services) {
        var newMenuItem = document.createElementNS("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul", "menuitem");
        newMenuItem.setAttribute("label", services[key]['title'])

        document.getElementById("mainDropdown").appendChild(newMenuItem);
    }
}
```

This code breaks at the appendChild command. Any ideas why?

Comment: I don't think you need to use createElementNS. It's already a XUL document so createElement should just create a XUL element by default.

Comment: @Gryllida yes I think so, or more generally, to insert tags in one namespace, into a document that has a different namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you 100% positive that document.getElementById("mainDropdown") is returning a non-null result?

Try breaking it down into pieces, and add some  debugging code to follow-along:

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById("mainDropdown");
if(dropDown) {
  alert("dropDown found!");
  dropDown.appendChild(newMenuItem);
}
```